# What type of file does MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE give back?

Tags: android, action, video-capture, android-intent

To capture video in an Android app, I'm using the `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` action, with `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to specify the location of the new video file. But how do I know what the MIME type is? Right now I just assume that it's “video/mp4”, but is there a way to get the video capture activity to tell me what the type is?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the file type that pops up on SD cards is [3gp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3gp). Not sure about the encoding.

As best I can tell, the EXTRA_OUTPUT is a copy of the video that doesn't replace the one saved in the standard location. So if you're just worried about having the correct extension, it doesn't *really* matter...

Comment: I've found at least one Android device where the extension does matter. ".3gp" worked, but ".mp4" did not work.